# Angular local variable to global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, geolocation

I am trying to get the country name from the JSON outside of the JSON scope but somehow it does not seem to pass, what am I doing wrong? I looked into the $rootScope but did not seem to get far with that. It's simple in principle, I would like to use the Country name as a variable in other scopes or on the page itself, also would like to use it in the Controller.cs (.net) to send it to the database

```
app.controller('PageController',
  function ($scope, $http) {

var analyticsCountry = "default";

$.getJSON('//www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?',

function (data) {
    $scope.testing = data;
    $scope.testing.country = data.geoplugin_countryName;
    //console.log($scope.testing.country);
    analyticsCountry = $scope.testing.country;
});

    console.log(analyticsCountry);

    $scope.GetTrendingCDsByCountry = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: "/CD/GetTrending?id=" + analyticsCountry

        })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.cds= data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
            });

    };  


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in the view. just bind it into `$scope` and you would be good to go. and as @Suren Srapyan said the callback would execute after the `console.log()` that has value `"default"` saved.

```
app.controller('PageController',
  function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.analyticsCountry = "default";
$scope.GetTrendingCDsByCountry = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'Get',
        url: "/CD/GetTrending?id=" + $scope.analyticsCountry

    })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.cds= data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });

};  

$.getJSON('//www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?',

function (data) {
    $scope.testing = data;
    $scope.testing.country = data.geoplugin_countryName;
    //console.log($scope.testing.country);
    $scope.analyticsCountry = $scope.testing.country;
    console.log($scope.analyticsCountry);
    $scope.GetTrendingCDsByCountry();
  });

});
```

Now it will work and would be easily accessed in the view as well.

Comment: yes i know how to do this, how ever i want to pass it as a variable so i can use it in other json routines in the PageController.js as well and not locally to be used in the view

Comment: this `$scope.analyticsCountry` can easily be accessed as a variable too in your pageController.

Comment: But after the callback is executed from the `http` request.

Comment: i extended the code a bit with another request from my DB to get the trending cd's for the country the user is in based on the ip address. Perhaps its more clear now what i try to do

Comment: Its done. See the code. I've just executed the function after your variable is defined

Comment: So is there another requirement that I could help.?

Comment: @EwaldBos any success?